# Re-Route based on Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-roles

I believe this is fairly simple.  I have a small site for database management for a customer.  When the user logs in, I want to reroute them to either the admin screen or to the user screen, based on their role. Currently it sends them to the Home screen.

Can I use `Roles.IsUserInRole()` in the `RouteConfig`?  I tried a few things but it's not liking it. What's easiest way to reroute based on Role? My `RouteConfig` is simply:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new 
            { 
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Index",
               id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
       );
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  think it's just fine to do this check in the `Index` action of the `HomeController` and use [`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to send the user to the right page.

Comment: that is certainly an easy way to do it.  Thanks!